# How does one customize the 3270 terminal login screen in VM/370?

Tags: emulation, mainframe, ibm370

When using a pre-built system image such as the "VM/370 sixpack" or "MVS Tur(n)key" under Hercules, when a user connects a 3270 terminal, a login screen comes up with a banned identifying the install (sixpack with one closer to the original VM/370 one, and Turnkey with a full custom one). How does one customize those screens? Is there a simple way to restore them to the original IBM provided one?

Comment: First you have to find an IBM custom system integrator.  Then you have to get out your checkbook and write a number with a lot of zeros after it ...

Comment: From what I remember from 40+ years ago this was just an assembler source file that you edited and put in the build.

Answer (score 4):

It is now 33 years since I last touched anything remotely connected (no pun intended) to VM/370, VM/SP, or MVS, and the little grey cells are now full of C#, Entity Framework, and SQL Server rather than BAL, CICS, and DL/I. However I did find this page which describes in detail the process for modifying the MVS VTAM 'map' for the signon screen:

[Customize MVS logon screen](https://web.archive.org/web/20221217103129/https://geronimo370.nl/s370/mvs-multiple-virtual-storage/customize-mvs-logon-screen/)

Comment: Stack Exchange discourages link-only answers, as the linked resource may become lost over time. Can you add a summary or other description to this answer to make it more complete?

Comment: @JacobKrall I did - I said the linked page 'describes in detail the process for modifying the MVS VTAM 'map' for the signon screen'. The key words here are 'in detail' since this is not a trivial process susceptible to summarisation, and to reproduce sufficient of the process here to make this a self-contained answer would require near-complete plagiarism of the original document.

Comment: I changed the link to an archive.org immutable URL as a starting step. The instructions are also specific to the TurnKey 4 MVS distribution, but are close enough for me to start figuring it generic instructions.